# Accessing public methods of a Class in a given scenario - C++

Tags: c++, oop

Consider a scenario(C++):

1. Class A, Class B, both derived from same parent class. For every instance of Class A, there is exactly one instance of Class B.
2. Class A keeps the pointer to Class B, such that instance of Class B is created in the Constructor of Class A.
3. Basically, in the implementation, Class A provides a way of accessing data from a file(XML). In fact, the methods in Class A in turn calls methods of Class B to retrieve or set value in the XML. For example, Class A has a getter function for retrieving tag value, after doing some operations at Class A level (mostly validations), Class A delegates to the getter function of Class B.

   ```
    void GetXMLTagValue (const string& sTagName, string& sTagValue)
   ```

Question:
In a certain scenario, I got an instance of Class B alone. And I need to invoke a public non static method of Class A. Is there a recommended way of achieving this?

Comment: there is no way of calling a public non static method of a class without instantiating the class.

Comment: *"I need to invoke a public non static method of Class A."* - you can only do that with an object of `class A`. Can it be any old object (create one when needed) or does it need to be a specific object?

Comment: @Galik I can create an Object of A and invoke the method,  but it's costly. (I may have to do this if no other alternative)

Comment: @object i don't think there is any alternative.

Comment: Well if you want to call an instance method then you need an instance. But if the instance method doesn't make any reference to member variables you may be able to make it static.

Comment: You said that for each instance of class A there exists an instance of class B. Is it true also the opposite? I mean, for each instance of class B there exists an instance of class A that owns it. If it's true, let the instance of B to have a reference to its parent and give it back.

Comment: Usually, with polymorphism, each type does the same job a different way. This inter-dependence you have between siblings sounds a little complex. Can something be re-factored here?

Answer (score 0):

Well the easiest way would be just keep a pointer back to A.  It'll be easy beacause A constructs B.

Nevertheless, it's worth questionning yourself about the design intention that's behind this special scenario.

You seem to implement the **[proxy design pattern](http://www.oodesign.com/proxy-pattern.html)**, where A is the proxy (GUI ?) and B the real subject (persistent business object ?).  The common base class  is the interface of both the real object and its proxy.  And A forwards the requests to B.

In principle the goal of the proxy is to provide a surrogate/placeholder to control access to the real object (Gang of 4).  Your special scenario is a little bit different, as B forwards something to A:

What's the intent ?

- must A be informed of some status changes of B ?  In this case, I'd suggest to use the [observer pattern](http://www.oodesign.com/observer-pattern.html) and see the A function to be called as the (virtual) callback function.  The advantage is that if you later come to the conclution that another object needs to be informed, it'll be easy to evolve.
- does B take responsibilities that A doesn't have ?  Should B manipulate A in a more extensive way ?  Then you could see B as being a [decorator](http://www.oodesign.com/decorator-pattern.html).  It works a little bit like a proxy.  If you adopt the decorator approach, you could have other intermediary objects being plugged between the final client and B as between B and A.   But seeing your one to one relationship and the fact that A creates B, this would be a more radical change in the design than adding observers; I'm not sure that it's what you're looking for in your design.